# Any good idea or software in obfuscating my ASP.NET framework 4 application?

Tags: javascript, c#, .net, security, obfuscation

For about 2 weeks i have been surfing the internet for finding any idea or a software to help me obfuscating my asp project i couldn't find any helpful way cause my main need is to obfuscate the `.JS` files in my project and i didn't find any build in tool for `VS2010`, cause i want to have an automated build including obfuscating however i have also tried searching a tool for `javascript` files obfuscating  including a command line way to communicate with the tool so i can call it in pre build event.

also if you can explain for me how to handle the injected `javascript` code in my `c#` code or no need to do this step.

I really appreciate your helps.

Answer (score -1):

Actually there is a plenty of different way to obfuscating javascript. One of the best solution is **gulp**

> Gulp is a task/build runner for development. It allows you to do a lot of stuff within your development workflow. You can compile sass files, uglify and compress js files and much more. The kicker for gulp is that its a streaming build system which doesn't write temp files.

It's really usefull tool to static files management. I suggest you to dive into it.

For example; lets look at following gulp definitian.

```
elixir(function(mix) {
    mix.styles([
        "font.css",
        "bootstrap.css",
        "custom.css"
    ], 'public/css/production.css').
    scripts([
        "jquery-2.2.4.min.js",
        "bootstrap.min.js",
        "app.js"
    ], 'public/js/production.js')
});
```

It concatenates font.css, bootstrap.css and custom.css files in order. And same for js files.Then performs compression and obfuscation.

You just need to run `gulp --production` for that.

There is a very good detailed documentation about using gulp with asp.net.
https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/client-side/using-gulp.html